# Logging only SSH authentication banner in Paramiko

Tags: python, logging, ssh, python-3.6, paramiko

I want to restrict the log details from the Python Paramiko library.

I'm using below config in logger:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s :::: %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S',
                    filename='sample.log', level=logging.DEBUG)
```

Console log from the above configuration:

```
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - DEBUG :::: Kex agreed: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - DEBUG :::: HostKey agreed: ssh-ed25519
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - DEBUG :::: Cipher agreed: aes128-ctr
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - DEBUG :::: MAC agreed: hmac-sha2-256
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - DEBUG :::: Compression agreed: none
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - DEBUG :::: kex engine KexCurve25519 specified hash_algo <built-in function 
openssl_sha256>
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - DEBUG :::: Switch to new keys ...
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - DEBUG :::: Adding ssh-ed25519 host key for 10.10.4.196: 
b'f14196dd49bc7fced6f6658236686957'
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - DEBUG :::: Trying discovered key b'64d107318fdaea41ba957bdccab827d1' in 
/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - DEBUG :::: userauth is OK
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - INFO :::: Authentication (publickey) failed.
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - DEBUG :::: userauth is OK
02/23/2021 05:19:47 - INFO :::: Authentication (password) successful!
**02/23/2021 05:19:47 - INFO :::: Welcome user**
```

I don't want to print all SSH-related details in the log but only the last line, i.e., *'Welcome user'*.
Please suggest if there is any such way possible.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

The line, you are interested in, seems to be an SSH authentication banner.

So if you want only that, disable all Paramiko logging and log the banner yourself. To retrieve the banner, use [`Transport.get_banner()`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.get_banner). If you are using `SSHClient` API (you should), get the `Transport` instance using [`SSHClient.get_transport()`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/client.html#paramiko.client.SSHClient.get_transport).